# binary search in java

Tags: java, binary-search

I have this code to binary search.

```
public class BinarySearch {

private static int location;
private static int a = 14;
static int[] numbers = new int[]{3, 6, 7, 11, 14, 16, 20, 45, 68, 79};

public static int B_Search(int[] sortedArray, int key) {
    int lowB = 0;
    int upB = sortedArray.length;
    int mid;
    while (lowB < upB) {
        mid = (lowB + upB) / 2;

        if (key < sortedArray[mid]) {
            upB = mid - 1;
        } else if (key > sortedArray[mid]) {
            lowB = mid + 1;
        } else {
            return mid;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    BinarySearch bs = new BinarySearch();
   location= bs.B_Search(numbers, a);
   if(location != -1){
       System.out.println("Find , at index of: "+ location);
   }
   else{
       System.out.println("Not found!");
   }
}
}
```

// output:
a=14

not Found!!

Why?

Comment: @rgettman Only this time the array is sorted :D

Comment: @MarounMaroun my array is sorted!

Comment: @MarounMaroun Can you tell me what is my mistake?

Comment: still basically an exact dupe of the original question, since the code has the same flaw as this one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, it's worth stepping through the code in the debugger to see if you can work out what's wrong. However, I know from experience that this particular bug can be tricky to diagnose.

You need to understand whether your upper and lower bounds are inclusive or exclusive. I suspect the upper bound is *exclusive*, but your lower bound is *inclusive* (which is pretty normal). That means this:

```
upB = mid - 1;
```

should actually be:

```
upB = mid;
```

We know that the right index isn't `mid`, but it *could* be the one lower. Your current code excludes that value... whereas the fixed code *only* excludes `mid`.

As other answers have shown, you *could* initialize and compare `upB` differently instead, and make it an *inclusive* upper bound. Personally I prefer to leave it exclusive, as so much of computer science works that way. But both will work.

Now, make sure you really understand what's going on here. *Don't* just copy the code and move on; work out how it all hangs together.

Answer (score 3):

When `lowB == upB`, you need to check whether `sortedArray[lowB] == key` before arbitrarily returning `-1`.

Comment: Only if you consider the upper bound to be inclusive - which seems unlikely given the way it's initialized, and the way the midpoint is found.

Answer (score 3):

You initialize upB with two different things. Initially it points after the end then it point to the last element:

Try this:

```
int upB = sortedArray.length-1;
int mid;
while (lowB <= upB) {
```

Comment: Did you notice the `<=` in the while statement. It prints 4 for me.

Comment: Or you could leave `upB` as an exclusive upper bound consistently - and just change the one statement which reassigns it. Given how pervasive exclusive upper bounds are throughout computer science, that's the way I prefer to do it.